# Is there anything like squeak etoys, which runs on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, smalltalk, children

Are any squeak's etoys like apps available for download to the ipad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Squeak running on iPad](http://news.squeak.org/2010/06/17/squeak-running-on-ipad/).

Comment: OK, I'll update my question, so it sounds less like "can it run at all" and more like "are there any working apps I can download". :P

Comment: One better than that: _Etoys_ running on iPad: http://croquetweak.blogspot.com/2010/06/squeak-etoys-on-ipad.html

Answer (score 0):

n.b. The Smalltalk mailing lists, accessible and searchable via http://forum.world.st/, are the first place to look for this type of question (the installation instructions below were the second hit for "iphone" there.

Bert ported eToys to the iPad, but as you can [read here](http://croquetweak.blogspot.com/2010/06/squeak-etoys-on-ipad.html), it seems more like a proof of concept than something you would use every day.

IIRC, even though Apple changed course to allow other languages on the iPhone/iPad, you still can't download code, which means you will not find Bert's port in the app store (I think downloading projects, which are Smalltalk, is prohibited). If you want to install eToys or any other Squeak variant onto your personal iPhone, you can start [here](http://forum.world.st/Pharo-on-the-iPhone-td3228851.html) to find out how.